# Merge or unmerge cells in spreadsheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to merge a cell with a neighbouring cells automatically based on the value in the cell value and without using VBA or the Format Cell > Alignment > Merge cells or Unmerge cells in a spreadsheet

For example if I had a specific String (say "Q1") in cell A1

```
   A    B    C     D
1  Q1
2
```

Is there a way to auto merge the the first 4 cells in row 1 to house this string

```
   A    B    C     D
1         Q1
2
```

also if the string changes to un-merge the cells?

Comment: With VBA? (Easy) Without it, as fas as I know it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no.  The only user-configured "automatic" formatting that doesn't involve VBA is called "conditional formatting," and conditional formatting does not have the capability (in any way) to merge or unmerge cells.